# How to use hibernate.properties file instead of hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, database, hibernate, properties

I am trying to connect to DB in a servlet using Hibernate.I have read that we can use either hibernate.cfg.xml or hibernate.properties file for configuration of session.For me it worked with xml. Now when I am trying to use properties instead of xml its not working.
It is saying that **hibernate.cfg.xml** **not found**.But nowhere I mentioned to use xml file and infact I have deleted that xml file.

Please Help me.
And Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Please share your hibernate.properties file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what i understood from hibernate the best thing to do is to define the mapping in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and other configurations in the `hibernate.properties`.

An alternative approach to configuration is to specify a full configuration in a file named `hibernate.cfg.xml`. This file can be used as a replacement for the `hibernate.properties` file or, if both are present, to override properties.

The `hibernate.cfg.xml` is also more convenient once you have to tune the Hibernate cache. It is your choice to use either hibernate.properties or `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Both are equivalent.

You can read more about this in the following link:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: how to replace <mapping resource=""> in properties file?.

Answer (score 20):

This code will call hibernate.cfg.xml by default:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
```

And this code will call hibernate.properties by default:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `.configure()` if you are using `hibernate.properties`. Below code is
`HibernateUtil` session factory implementation.

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
            = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(LookUpModel.class);
        return configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("There is issue in hibernate util");
    }
}
```

hibernate.properites file

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
hibernate.connection.username = root
hibernate.connection.password = passsword
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **database** from a **servlet** then you should define a **DataSource** in your server and point one hibernate property at that instead of defining everything via all the other hibernate properties you're probably using now.

This has the benefit of permitting you to define connection pooling and other connection related parameters independently of your application.

For example, your production environment is likely to have a different database password than your test and development environments.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FactoryConfiguration {

    private static FactoryConfiguration factoryConfiguration;
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private FactoryConfiguration(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("hibernate.properties"));
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
        .addProperties(properties)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static FactoryConfiguration getInstance(){
        return (factoryConfiguration == null) ? factoryConfiguration = new FactoryConfiguration() : factoryConfiguration;
    }

    public Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add annonated entity class as below. **This works for me.**

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
   try{
       properties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.properties"));
   }catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("cannot load properties file.");
   }
    sessionFactory = new Configuration().mergeProperties(properties).addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class).buildSessionFactory();
```

> "hibernate.propeties" is the file that have hibernate configuration and please remember to give your hibernate property file location correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above said.
Via StandardServiceRegistry. To load a random properties in property format as resource:

```java
    String resourceName = "MyHibernate.properties";
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .loadProperties(resourceName).build();
    sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry)
            .addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class)
            .buildMetadata()
            .buildSessionFactory();
```

As xml resource:

```java
    String resourceName = "MyHibernate.cfg.xml";
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure(resourceName).build();
    sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry)
            .addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class)
            .buildMetadata()
            .buildSessionFactory();
```

Via Configuration. Load as random file path,
as property file path

```java
        String filePath = "filePath/MyHibernate.properties";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                .addProperties(properties)
                .addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
```

as xml file path

```java
        String filePath = "filePath/MyHibernate.cfg.xml";
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                .configure(new File(filePath));
                .addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
```

Load as resource,
as xml resource

```java
    String resourceXmlName = "MyHibernate.cfg.xml";
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure(resourceXmlName)
            .addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();
```

To load properties as resource, load as standard path as described above, but transform resource name to file path like this:

```java
    String resourceName = "MyHibernate.properties";
    URL fl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
    //fl can be null, up to you how to handle this
    System.out.println (fl.getPath()));
```