# Hibernate Properties or configuration file to use

Tags: java, hibernate

For hibernate project what is recommended to use `hibernate.properties` file or `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.
What to use??

And please can u also specify why to use properties instead configuration and vice versa

which use is best hibernate.properties file OR hibernate.cfg.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hibernate.properties is the old way to represent the connection information, for newest versions (2.0+), it has been replaced by the XML-based configuration file, since it is more flexible and has more features.

However, there's a thread explaining how to combine them both, you should have a look at this thread: [How to use hibernate.properties file instead of hibernate.cfg.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908606/how-to-use-hibernate-properties-file-instead-of-hibernate-cfg-xml).

You should also have a look to the Hibernate documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html, chapter 3.7. XML configuration file.